# Replacing ¼ in a php string possible?

Tags: php, string

How can i replace `¼` in a php string 
I just tried the following code but it's not working

```
 $directions=str_replace("¼", "1/4", $directions);
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: this is working for me $directions=str_replace(chr(188), "1/4", $directions);

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be suffering as a result of PHP's inability to gracefully handle Unicode.

The character in question can be represented in some versions of extended ASCII, and not in others. It can also be represented in Unicode, by a multi-byte sequence.

What works depends on the input (HTTP input), script (php file), and any other sources (database etc) encoding being consistent.

This character happens to be representable in both ASCII and Unicode, but it seems like you are working on an application that does need to be Unicode.

Once your encoding problem is solved, you can use multi-byte string functions:

```
echo mb_ereg_replace("¼", "1/4", "¼ of things");
```

Answer (score -2):

this works for me

```
$directions=str_replace(chr(188), "1/4", $directions);
```

Comment: imperfect: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/315b40befadaa72f9b4e285046d1bb886ba01471